# Insert CSS into mixin

Tags: css, sass

I have come across a situation where we have this particular cheeky Safari-only styling issue we want to address. I can target this bug by using:

```
@media screen and (min-color-index:0) and(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
  @media { 
    /*======================
    ----MY CSS GOES HERE----
    =======================*/
  } 
}
```

[(Source)](http://browserstrangeness.bitbucket.org/css_hacks.html#safari)

Instead of using this bulk piece of CSS, I'd like to create a mixin, so I could use something like:
`@include safariOnly(p { color: red; });`

How would I go about creating this?

Comment: I just tried, but sass didn't allow empty `@media` directives.

Comment: Which safari styling bug is it? Might be a good fallback or vendor-prefix you can use...